# Additional "Images And Links" fields - corect way

Tags: articles, images, joomla3.8

Just edited administrator/component/com_content/models/forms/article.xml to add more Images fields. The control is very user-friendly.

[image]

Is there a way of doing it more right without changing core Joomla components?

Comment: Why not use Joomla custom fields?  You could use the image type...

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey The image type is just a dropdown with text, but just a second ago I found "Media" type which is exactly what is shown. Cool. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome.  I knew there was one that would work, just couldn't remember the name before coffee.  :)

Comment: I added as an answer for anyone looking to see if this thread was solved or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Joomla custom fields instead.  The media field should work: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Media_Field